# Difficulty getting child of node selected with attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm having trouble selecting the `s:latin` child node of the `s:fontSlot`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<s:fontScheme name="CustomFontFamily" previewSlot1="title" previewSlot2="body" xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <s:fontSlots>
        <s:fontSlot name="title">
            <s:latin typeface="Segoe UI Light" />
            <s:ea typeface="" />
            <s:cs typeface="Segoe UI Light" />
            <s:font script="Arab" typeface="Segoe UI Light" />
            ...
        </s:fontSlot>
        ...
    </s:fontSlots>
</s:fontScheme>
```

**Keep in mind that this is in Google Chrome only, and it seems to prefer that [all namespaces be dropped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181087/xml-findsomeelement-pulling-values-with-jquery-from-xml-with-namespace#answer-10192959).**

The document is correctly parsed and wrapped:

```
var $xml = $($.parseXML(xml));
```

The slot.name variable correctly returns, in this case "title".

I have tried:

```
$xml.find('fontSlot[name="' + slot.name + '"] latin')

$xml.find('fontSlot[name="' + slot.name + '"]').children('latin')
```

Both of these return nothing. However, I noticed that when I `console.log`'d the following:

```
$xml.find('fontSlot[name="' + slot.name + '"]')
```

The correct parent node is found, and:

```
$xml.find('fontSlot[name="' + slot.name + '"]').children()
```

Returns a list of nodes, `s:latin` included. I then tried to filter:

```
$xml.find('fontSlot[name="' + slot.name + '"]').children().filter('latin')
```

This returns nothing. So I decided to try with the namespace:

```
$xml.find('fontSlot[name="' + slot.name + '"]').children().filter('s\\:latin')
```

And **this actually returned the desired node**! So I went back and tried to simplify:

```
$xml.find('fontSlot[name="' + slot.name + '"] s\\:latin')
```

And again, nothing. I was able to simplify it a little:

```
$xml.find('fontSlot[name="' + slot.name + '"]').find('latin')
```

I still feel like the very first attempt ought to work. Why doesn't it? This seems like a bug in jQuery/Sizzle to me. Or am I missing something?

Additional details: I am using jQuery 2.1.1 and I have also tried non-escaped versions of the above namespaced selectors.

Answer (score 1):

I concur that the selectors seem to act differently for different methods and different browsers.

`find()` and `children()` as example in Chrome seem to work differently with regard to namespace. Firefox is consistent however for all methods

While Chrome doesn't like `s\\:fontSlot` Firefox doesn't like `fontSlot` by itself.

What is strange is that logging `node.tagName` both browsers output the same with the `s:tagName` format.

Having played with this a bit it seems the only safe cross browser approach is to use 2 selectors for each traverse:

```
var slot={name:'title'};    
$.post('/echo/xml/', {xml: xml}, function(xml){        
    $(xml).find('s\\:fontSlot, fontSlot').children('s\\:latin, latin').each(function(){
       console.log(this.tagName); //s:latin in both chrome and FF
    });        
},'xml');
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hncypc5c/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: I'm not concerned about Firefox, though the info is interesting. Unfortunately, this answer does not address my main issue of why the first find call fails.

Comment: I do think it's a bug, not sure if Chrome or jQuery but if you use both selectors all the time I think it will work. Not sure which `first` you mean

Comment: I'm referring to: `$xml.find('fontSlot[name="' + slot.name + '"] latin')` where I'm using a simple ancestor descendant selector within a single find. I have tested your suggestion, and it does work, it's just not as simple as it ought to be. But it looks like `filter` and `children` work the same (requiring the namespace).